# Mobile UI issue in lightning buttonMenu Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, mobile, ui

I just notice that Lightning:buttonMenu aura component size bigger in the mobile after winter 20 Salesforce release.

Is it any way to control the size as previous because it's breaking our UI.
Its working fine in LXP and Community.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and purposely done for A11Y reasons (Touch targets should have a minimum target size of 44 pixels (px) wide 44 pixels tall).

You'd have to overwrite the styles for mobile.